# Best place to put a resource file in a JSF application

Tags: jsf, maven, jsf-2

In a regular java application if I have a static resource file I am used to using a ClassLoader to get it.  However I have discovered that this is a problem in a JSF web app.

First of all, maven won't copy the resource file from **src** to **target** and then package it into the **war** file unless you specifically add a **resource** tag in **pom.xml**.   That's a pain, but even worse is that it seems that tag stops the **generated-sources** phase from copying in the JPA MetaModel -- breaking the package.

So it seems that such a resource file should probably go somewhere else, like somewhere under **WEB-INF**.  Can someone point me to what the common practice is for this?   Do I still use the class loader's **getResourceAsStream()** method or something else?

UPDATE (some clarification):

What I had been using was this in the **pom.xml** file:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/java/com/myapp/app/resource</directory>
      <targetPath>com/myapp/app/resource</targetPath>
    </resource>    
</resources>
```

Unless you put that in, the files won't be included in the target.  Then to use the file I do this:

```
InputStream ris = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/myapp/app/resource/words.txt");
```

This works -- I get the data from **words.txt** just the way I would if I were a java desktop app.  The problem is with that when I put that in the **pom.xml**, the next time I do a "clean and build" operation the JPA metamodel gets deleted and not created again, resulting in compile-time errors.

The funny thing is that the Netbeans 7.0 IDE *does* get the Metamodel generated somehow.  But it isn't stored in the **target** directory it is squirreled away in the **cache** directory under **~/.netbeans**.

UPDATE #2 (another question):

I notice there is a method:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(String ..);
```

Is this what I should be using instead?   However I don't want the resource file exposed to the outside world -- I would rather have it hidden in **WEB-INF**.

Comment: Can you please reword and ask a direct question? I have no idea what you are saying after trying to read your question twice.

Comment: Regarding update 2: you can just put it in `/WEB-INF` yourself and reference as such in `ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()` path. However, I'd prefer putting it in the classpath and thus fix the Maven problem.

Comment: I would prefer that too.   Maven is pretty opaque to me I wish I could find decent documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

To close this question for the benefit of anyone else that has the same issue, I will post how I resolved this.   Basically this works:

```
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    InputStream ris = fc.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/misc/words.txt");
```

I chose to place the **words.txt** file in the **/resources** directory, but I could have moved it to somewhere inside of **/WEB-INF**.  Since the Maven plug-in copies the resources directory unchanged to the target, then there is nothing new to be configured there.